# Putting the \title of a BeamerClass presentation in a \block

Tags: beamer

I'm using a hand made `beamer` theme that uses the corporate identity standards of my university. However, the `\title` text on the `\titlepage` is not set in a `\block` environment as it is, e.g., in the Darmstadt theme.

[image]

Is there a LaTeX command that actually toggles this feature on or off? If yes, is there a way to change the look of the `\block` environment of the `\title` without affecting the remaining `\block` environments on non-title-page slides?

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer} % handout 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{upb}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % besseren Umbruch
\usepackage{booktabs} % spezielle Tabellen zulassen
\usepackage{textpos}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[rounded=true,shadow=true]
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{phx}
\institute{University of Paderborn}
\begin{document}
 \frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The theme `upd` is available [here](http://homepages.uni-paderborn.de/jimknopf/beamerthemeupb/) ([zip-file](http://homepages.uni-paderborn.de/jimknopf/beamerthemeupb/beamerthemeupb.zip))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please provide a full minimal example. Based on the information that you wish a style like `Darmstard` you use the definition of `Darmstadt`:

```
\setbeamercolor*{title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]
```

Full example without the unknown theme `upd`

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer} % handout 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usetheme{upb}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % besseren Umbruch
\usepackage{booktabs} % spezielle Tabellen zulassen
\usepackage{textpos}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor*{title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg,}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{phx}
\institute{University of Paderborn}
\begin{document}
 \frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Result with the usage of the theme `upd`:

[image]

Comment: @phx: I downloaded the theme and it works as expected.

Comment: This works fine. The only problem is now that the frame titles on the subsequent slides are white and therefore invisible.

Comment: @phx: I edited my post. I changed `titlelike` to `title`

Comment: Ok, this actually does the trick setting the frame title color back to blue

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=upbblue,bg=structure.fg}